# Parent App access vs Events in Flex Modules

Tags: apache-flex, events, communication, module, tightly-coupled-code

Inspired by [this Flex question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039437/flex-3-passing-data-from-modules-to-parent-application-to-switch-views-in-the-vie), is it seen as better practice to dispatch an event back to the parent app, as opposed to calling a method on the instance of the parent app, from within a module?
To me it seems that the module shouldn't know what methods are available at the parent, as such approach leads to tight coupling.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found my answer [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=modular_7.html#188322).